# Adding Pagination And Column Sorting To ZingChart Grids

Tags: javascript, charts, datagrid, grid, zingchart

Is it possible to add pagination and sorting to zingchart grids. https://www.zingchart.com/docs/chart-types/grid/?q=javascript%20grids%20%7C%20zingchartasset%201#grid__data

Answer (score 1):

The ZingChart grid module is a read-only grid and currently does not support pagination or sorting.  We may have a better solution in the near future.